# adicionar atributo para um ou mais select option desconhecido

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-eventos

Tenho um código que define dinamicamente os campos inputs.
Em um contexto, tenho vários selects sendo definidos, e não conheço previamente o nome ou seu id.
Os inputs select e os options dos selects são definidos dinamicamente, via ajax.
O primeiro option é selecionado por padrão

```
<option value="">Selecione um valor...</option>
```

Nenhum option tem o atributo selected definido ou apenas o option mencionado acima.
Não conheço nenhuma informação previamente, pois o desenvolvedor fez código generico para todo o sistema e manteve por padrão, o primeiro option de cada select, com o valor vindo da base de dados.
Gostaria de saber se alguém consegue me ajudar.
Deixo abaixo fragmentos do código.
Obrigado

```
$.ajax({
    url: url.properties,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {category: category}
})
.done(function(properties) {
    window.categoryProperties = properties;
    loadProperties();
})

function loadProperties() {
if ($.isEmptyObject(window.categoryProperties) === false) {
    var html = '';

    // metadados
    html += '<div class="form-group row">';
    html += '<label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Caracter&iacute;sticas</label>';
    html += '<div class="col-sm-10">';
    html += '<label for="inputEmail3" class="col-form-label">Valor</label>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';

    $.each(window.categoryProperties, function(index, property) {
        html += '<div class="form-group row">';
        html += '<label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">' + property.description + '<span class="required">*</span></label>';
        html += '<div class="col-sm-10">';
        html += createFieldPropertyValue(property.id, property.type, property.options, property.options.selected);
        html += '</div>'
        html += '</div>'

    });
} else {
    var html;
    html += '<div class="form-group row">';
    html += '<label for="formGroupExampleInput">Escolha uma categoria</label>';
    html += '</div>'
}

// método substitudo para inserir as div's
$('.selected_feature_data').html(html);
$('#tblProperties').find('.select2').css('width', '100%');
$('#tblProperties').find('.select2').select2({language: "pt-BR"});
}

function createFieldPropertyValue(property, type, options) {
switch (type) {
    case 'text':
        field = '<input type="text" name="TB_PRP_TIP_CPO_VLR_CPO_OPC[' + property + ']" class="form-control requiredField">';
        break;
    case 'select':
        var classSelect2 = '';
        if (options.length > 5) {
            classSelect2 = 'select2';
        }

        field = '<select name="TB_PRP_TIP_CPO_VLR_CPO_OPC[' + property + ']" class="form-control requiredField ui-selectmenu ' + classSelect2 + '">';
        field += '<option value="">Selecione uma opção...</option>';
            $.each(options, function(index, val) {
                field += '<option value="' + val.id + '">' + val.description + '</option>';
            });
        field += '</select>';
        break;
    case 'number':
        field = '<input type="text" name="TB_PRP_TIP_CPO_VLR_CPO_OPC[' + property + ']" class="form-control requiredField mask-number" value="">';
        break;
}

return field;
}
```

Eu preciso alterar o select dinamicamente.
Quando o usuário selecionar um item e um dos selects, eu preciso adicionar o atributo selected.
Mas nada funciona.
Tentei trigger, tentei usar attr, setAttributes, entre outros

Comment: Willian, confesso que fiquei confuso sobre o que exatamente você deseja fazer?

Comment: Perdão.
Eu preciso alterar o select dinamicamente.
Quando o usuário selecionar um item e um dos selects, eu preciso adicionar o atributo selected.
Mas nada funciona.
Tentei trigger, tentei usar attr, setAttributes, entre outros

Comment: Você pode usar `.val()` do jQuery, se você souber como selecionar o elemento `select`. Assim: `$("#id_do_select").val("valor_do_option");`

Comment: Pela classe que está no HTML creio que você está utilizando o Selectmenu do Jquery UI. Verifique a documentação do mesmo para saber como selecionar um item via javascript. https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#product-selection . Acredito que utilizando o metodo da biblioteca você conseguirá forçar a opção selecionada na interface gerada (o select na verdade esta montado com UL e LI) a refletir no select (que está por baixo dos panos oculto)